# Почему оптимизации ухудшили время и как оптимизировать запрос?

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня имеется запрос - Вывести всех обучающихся и указать оценку по курсу «Литература» для всех, кто его проходил в формате: ФИО, Оценка:

```
SELECT T1.FIO, T2.ItogovayaOcenka 
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT ( SELECT Chelovek.FIO 
                         FROM Chelovek 
                         WHERE Chelovek.NumerPassporta = ObuchayushchijsyaNumerPassporta) FIO  
       FROM Ocenka) T1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ( SELECT Chelovek.FIO 
                     FROM Chelovek 
                     WHERE Chelovek.NumerPassporta = ObuchayushchijsyaNumerPassporta ) FIO,
                   ItogovayaOcenka 
            FROM Ocenka 
            WHERE ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie='Литература') T2 ON T2.FIO=T1.FIO;
```

Ниже его физический план:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пока что не добавляя индексы, изменяю запрос на такой(оптимизированный запрос):

```sql
WITH 
T1 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT ( SELECT Chelovek.FIO 
                          FROM Chelovek 
                          WHERE Chelovek.NumerPassporta = ObuchayushchijsyaNumerPassporta) FIO  
        FROM Ocenka ),
T2 as ( SELECT ( SELECT Chelovek.FIO 
                 FROM Chelovek 
                 WHERE Chelovek.NumerPassporta = ObuchayushchijsyaNumerPassporta) FIO ,
               ItogovayaOcenka 
        FROM Ocenka 
        WHERE ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie='Литература'),
JOINED AS ( SELECT T1.FIO, T2.ItogovayaOcenka 
            FROM T1 
            LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.FIO=T1.FIO)
SELECT * FROM JOINED;
```

Но показатели замеров времени через DATEDIFF показали, что первый(неоптимизированный запрос) показывает себя лучше.
И его физический план не изменился:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как лучше оптимизировать первый запрос?**

Таблица Chelovek определена таким образом:

```
CREATE TABLE Chelovek               
(
NumerPassporta NVARCHAR(200) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL CHECK (NumerPassporta!=''), 
FIO NVARCHAR(200) UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK(FIO !='')
);
```

Таблица Ocenka:

```
CREATE TABLE Ocenka
(
    Id INT IDENTITY ,--PRIMARY KEY,
    PromezhutochnyeOcenka1 INT NOT NULL CHECK (PromezhutochnyeOcenka1>0),--ПромежуточныеОценки
    PromezhutochnyeOcenka2 INT NOT NULL CHECK (PromezhutochnyeOcenka2>0),--ПромежуточныеОценки
    PromezhutochnyeOcenka3 INT NOT NULL CHECK (PromezhutochnyeOcenka3>0),--ПромежуточныеОценки
    ItogovayaOcenka int NOT NULL CHECK (ItogovayaOcenka>0),
    ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL CHECK (ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie!=''),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN_KursNazvanie FOREIGN KEY (ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie)  REFERENCES ZHurnal_Ocenok(KursNazvanie),
    ObuchayushchijsyaNumerPassporta NVARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL CHECK (ObuchayushchijsyaNumerPassporta!=''),
    --FOREIGN KEY (ObuchayushchijsyaNumerPassporta) REFERENCES Obuchayushchijsya(NumerPassporta)
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY_KEY_Id PRIMARY KEY(Id)
    
);
```

Эти таблицы заполняются в цикле:

```
Declare @_NumPass varchar(11)
Set @_NumPass = ''

Declare @_FIO varchar(80)
Set @_FIO = ''

Declare @_PromezhutochnyeOcenka1 int
Set @_PromezhutochnyeOcenka1 = 0

Declare @_PromezhutochnyeOcenka2 int
Set @_PromezhutochnyeOcenka2 = 0

Declare @_PromezhutochnyeOcenka3 int
Set @_PromezhutochnyeOcenka3 = 0

Declare @_ItogovayaOcenka int
Set @_ItogovayaOcenka = 0

Declare @_ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie varchar(80)
Set @_ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie = ''

Declare @RandNumForSubject int
Set @RandNumForSubject=0






Declare @top int 
Set @top = 1000000

Declare @cnt int
Set @cnt = 0

While @cnt < @top
Begin   
    set @_NumPass = convert(varchar(36),newid())
    set @_FIO = convert(varchar(36),newid())
    set @RandNumForSubject = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 7+1
    IF @RandNumForSubject = 1
        BEGIN
            set @_ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie='Matematica'
        END;
    IF @RandNumForSubject = 2
        BEGIN
            set @_ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie='История'
        END;
    IF @RandNumForSubject = 3
        BEGIN
            set @_ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie='Литература'
        END;
    IF @RandNumForSubject = 4
        BEGIN
            set @_ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie='География'
        END;
    IF @RandNumForSubject = 5
        BEGIN
            set @_ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie='Базовая'+'информатика'
        END;
    IF @RandNumForSubject = 6
        BEGIN
            set @_ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie='Биология'
        END;
    IF @RandNumForSubject = 7
        BEGIN
            set @_ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie='Химия'
        END;
    set @_PromezhutochnyeOcenka1 = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5+1
    set @_PromezhutochnyeOcenka2 = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5+1
    set @_PromezhutochnyeOcenka3 = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5+1
    set @_ItogovayaOcenka = (@_PromezhutochnyeOcenka1+@_PromezhutochnyeOcenka2+@_PromezhutochnyeOcenka3)/3


    Insert Into Chelovek values (@_NumPass,@_FIO)

    Insert Into Ocenka values (@_PromezhutochnyeOcenka1,@_PromezhutochnyeOcenka2,@_PromezhutochnyeOcenka3,@_ItogovayaOcenka,@_ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie,@_NumPass)


    Set @cnt = @cnt + 1
End
```

Comment: *изменяю запрос на такой(оптимизированный запрос)* o_O это с какого перепугу он "оптимизированный"-то, позвольте узнать? *Пока что не добавляя индексы* Гениально... Вы хоть планы своих запросов смотрели? *Но показатели замеров времени через DATEDIFF показали* нечто, в принципе не имеющее смысла они могли показать, и не более того. *почему с индексами оптимизация стала хуже.* Потому что индексы не создают по некоему мистическому наитию или позыву от левой пятки. Индексы должны отражать структуру запроса. Но в Вашем случае - надо зачеркнуть всё и составить запрос заново.

Comment: @Akina, физические планы этих двух запросов действительно не отличается друг от друга...

Comment: Это вполне ожидаемо. Вы лучше озвучьте саму задачу - ибо на запрос страшно смотреть...

Comment: @Akina, у меня по левую  и правую сторону от LEFT JOIN в запросе есть почти одинаковые selectы, они отличаются только distint , можно ли их как-то оптимизировать? **Я хочу оптимизировать по времени первый запрос** (либо индексами, либо изменением логики самого запроса, либо ими обоими)

Comment: *по левую и правую сторону от LEFT JOIN* у Вас подзапросы. И скажите спасибо, что у Вас сервер умный - глупый вообще бы игнорировал наличие любых индексов, ибо результат подзапроса, в отличие от таблиц, никаких индексов не имеет в принципе.

Comment: Через datediff кстати мерять не стоит. Set statistics time on (и io on) даст точный результат. Покажите план, а лучше - дайте скрипт для создания таблиц и заполнения данных - можно будет более точно сказать, что менять и как ускорять

Comment: @Akina,  я добавил физический план, можете подсказать, как читая его ,осуществить оптимизацию ?

Comment: @PashaPash, дополнил вопрос, можете посмотреть?

Comment: Я тем не менее повторю, если это не было замечено или было неверно понято. **озвучьте саму задачу**. Я не до конца понимаю, что ВЫ пытаетесь получить, но если мои предположения верны, то составленный запрос следует забыть как страшный сон и написать заново - но в лаконичной и логичной форме, допускающей к тому же нормальную оптимизацию.

Comment: @Akina, забыть нужно оба запроса или только второй, который типо "оптимизированный" ?

Comment: Оба, оба... Кстати, вот Ваши коды в виде [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b117820fb1c6195380b951e64033ca97)...

Comment: А какая задача? получить итоговую оценку по литературе для всех людей по ObuchayushchijsyaNumerPassporta из оценок? я просто пытаюсь понять, зачем вам второе обращение к Chelovek :)

Comment: @PashaPash, нужно вывести всех обучающихся и указать оценку по курсу «Литература» для всех, кто его проходил в формате: ФИО, Оценка

Comment: обучающийся - это просто человек в таблице Chelovek? или это человек, прошедший хотя бы один курс (не обязательно по литературе)?

Comment: @PashaPash, это просто человек, у которого есть паспорт и ФИО

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Под задачу "нужно вывести всех обучающихся и указать оценку по курсу «Литература» для всех, кто его проходил в формате: ФИО, Оценка" запрос выглядит гораздо проще. Нужно взять всех учащихся и сделать left join на оценки по предмету. Примерно так:

```
SELECT FIO, ItogovayaOcenka 
from Chelovek 
left join Ocenka on NumerPassporta = ObuchayushchijsyaNumerPassporta 
    and ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie=N'Литература' -- не забывайте про N'' для nvarchar!
```

План:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оптимизация - добавить индекс под поиск по ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie и выборку ItogovayaOcenka, ObuchayushchijsyaNumerPassporta - его и подсказывает SSMS:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ocenkaPassportByKurs
ON [dbo].[Ocenka] ([ZHurnal_OcenokKursNazvanie])
INCLUDE ([ItogovayaOcenka],[ObuchayushchijsyaNumerPassporta])
```

План:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что такое параметр cost? Это стоимость операции ?
Почему тогда операция Index Seek берет 100% записей(стрелочка толстая) и её выполнение стоит так мало? 
Заметил одну вещь: чем cost выше, тем меньше количество записей и наоборот: чем больше записей, тем меньше cost

Comment: 100% записей - это % реально выбранных строк относительно оценочного количества этих строк до выполнения (estimated). Если есть большое расхождение - то или статистика в таблице устарела (по ней sql server оценивает количество записей без явной их выборки), либо план собран изначально под другие параметры запроса. А Cost % - это какую часть от общей стоимости выборки занимает конкретный блок с точки зрения оптимизатора.